# How can I interact with a View I just showed using presentViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a view that I use for adding data into a table. I show this view using `presentViewController`:

```
AddViewController *avc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addview"];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This `UINavigationController` is the root view controller for a `UIViewController` that displays the add controls.

I trigger this `UINavigationController` from a couple of different places in my project and I'd like to have slightly different text for each. How can I interact with the `UIViewController` from where I call `presentViewController`, or otherwise change `UIViewController` depending on where it was invoked?

Comment: I don't think I understood correctly. AddViewController is a UINavigationController? Or is just one ViewController that will be displayed inside your navigation controller? What you really want it's to change something inside "AddViewController", which is the view controller that will be presented?

Comment: `AddViewController` is the `UINavigationController`, sorry for the confusion. I want to access the `UIViewController` which is its root view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can access the rootView controller of your navigation controller like this:

```
UINavigationController *yourNavigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerID"];

YourRootController *yourRootController = (YourRootController*)[yourNavigationController topViewController];

yourRootController.someproperty = someValue
```

Than, just change some desired property in the view controller that you just get.
Please, tell me if it was something like this that you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController *controller= (UIViewController)[self.navigationController subviews] count-2 ];
```

controller is the second-last view controller on the stack. which is the one that called add.

depending upon the value for `[controler class]` , you can set the text.